# 2 Buttons in ListView in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom ListView in which there are 2 buttons and a textview in each row.

I want to change the text of the clicked button. How to identify that which button of which row has been clicked and then how to change the text of the same button.

Comment: Sample code will be a great help..!!

Comment: in getView method of adapter you can define button click event and from there you can all your task | depend on your requirement

Comment: Thanks for reply..!!
I did the same but after doing so the difined action is performed on the last button only even if I click 1st button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How to identify that which button of which row has been clicked
```

Use onClickListener(). When a button is clicked that button's onClickListener will be called.

```
How to change the text of the same button
```

In onClickListener() you can do something like

```
yourTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0)); //replace 0,0,0 with the rgb value of the color
```

Comment: after onClickListener(), the defined action is performed on the last button only even if I click 1st button.
How to do it for exactly clicked button, like if I press the button of 2nd row, how to identify that button of secon row has been clicked out of 10 rows..?

Comment: you can identify them by the id of the buttons. b1 = buttons. findViewBy(R.id.Button1)

Comment: How to identify which button has been clicked..?

Comment: in the onClick(View v) function, you can call v.getId() on the incoming view. if that is equal to R.id.button1.. it was button1. then you can call button1.setText() or whatever you need to do with that button.

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of example for the having Different Clickable Views in one single ListView

like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821871/android-how-to-fire-onlistitemclick-in-listactivity-with-buttons-in-list)

point should keep

You need set the listener to each view in getView (don't create in each time in get view just pass already created one or can pass this and implement the listener in same adapter class)

You 'll also required the `row position` so can use different logic l`ike get & Set tag` or `get button view parent (which will be list row)` as in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188741/android-listview-get-textview-value-at-the-position-where-the-toggle-button-is-c/11188879#11188879)