# Android : How to identify button click in a Listview having more than one button

Tags: android, listview

My custom Listview has more than one button, how can I identify which button has been clicked ? I want to do different things on action of different buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create local variables for buttons inside getview method and set onClickListener for each button in a row.

Also have a look at this -:
[2 Buttons in ListView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266860/2-buttons-in-listview-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

In custom adapder of your `ListView` you must be creating objects of each button in its `getView()` method.

Just set the `onClickListener` on the buttons and perform the action on each buttons in its `onClick()`.